# Is there a way to return the jsonpath match response to not be a list in Python?

Tags: python, jsonpath

I am extracting data from a JSON that has many nested fields. It is for this reason I opted to use Jsonpath to get the required fields. My issue, however, comes when I have got the results from the request which comes as a list. Is there a way to change how this response comes because it is giving me a bit of a headache when it comes to dumping the results in a JSON output file.
Below is a snippet of the JSON I am pulling from (I have used dummy data to protect identities):

```
"contactPoint": {
                "name": "Stack Overflow",
                "email": "stack.overflow@email.com",
                "telephone": "+44 xxx xxx xxx",
                "url": "http://www.dummydata.stack"
              },
```

I have managed to successfully extract the right data using jsonpath as follows:

```
r = requests.get(api_url)
contracts_json = r.json()

        contact_name_expr = parse(
            '$..records[*].releases[0].parties[0].contactPoint.name')
        contact_name = [
            match.value for match in contact_name_expr.find(contracts_json)]

        email_expr = parse(
            '$..records[*].releases[0].parties[0].contactPoint.email')
        contact_email = [
            match.value for match in email_expr.find(contracts_json)]

        contact_tel_expr = parse(
            '$..records[*].releases[0].parties[0].contactPoint.telephone')
        contact_tel = [
            match.value for match in contact_tel_expr.find(contracts_json)]
```

I the append them to an output dictionary which I will then dump into a JSON file as follows:

```
        output_dict['contacts'].append(
            {'contact_name': contact_name, 'contact_email': contact_email, 'contact_phone': contact_tel})
```

And the output I get is as follows after json dumping to a JSON file:

```
"contacts": [
            {
                "contact_name": [
                    "Stack Overflow"
                ],
                "contact_email": [
                    "stack.overflow@email.com"
                ],
                "contact_phone": [
                    "+44 xxx xxx xxx"
                ]
            }
        ],
```

Instead of this:

```
"contacts": [
            {
                "contact_name": "Stack Overflow",
                "contact_email": "stack.overflow@email.com",
                "contact_phone": "+44 xxx xxx xxx"
            }
        ],
```

I'd really appreciate your help in understanding this

Comment: Why did you make all of those into lists?  The short answer is just to add `[0]` at the end of your three statements, to select the first item from the list.  But if each match is only going to return one entry, then you don't really need a list comprehension at all.   
 Just `contact_name_expr.find(contracts.json)[0].value` should work, right?

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for that. I have edited the code to show the request call. The file is not `contracts.json` but `contracts_json` which is the JSON response to the call made and is actually a JSON file. When I try that I get `list index is out of range` and  when I omit the `[0]`, I get `'list' object has no attribute 'value'`

Comment: "list index is out of range" means that entry is empty.  Does EVERY contact have all three pieces of information, every time?

Comment: JSONPath always returns a list. So you have to do the post-processing to get the single value from the list. `contact_name[0]`